# HOW DO I MOVE THIS DIV UP TO BE ALLIGNED WITH THE FORM BOX

Tags: html, css, css-position

newbie coder here again... i'm trying to move the .contactdetails up to sit alongside with the form at the top of the page ...but i'm not too good with all the CSS commands, i've tried margins and stuff but it just goes all over the place.
2. Also how do i get the social media icons to position horizontally inside the contact details box.

http://aasunm01.wdd1516.bbkweb.org/Assignment%201/contactus.html

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve] in your question. Also don't use all caps in your title as it reads like YOU'RE SHOUTING

Comment: sincere apologies, still new here. I wasn't shouting ..just wasnt thinking much and was typing out of desperation :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the alignment of the box, the easiest way is to put the `.contactdetails` box before the contact form box in your HTML code.

For the social media icons: don't use a list. remove the `<ul>` and `<li>` stuff around the `<a>` tags.

Comment: Brilliant that worked, thanks so much stegschreck